# Suspend execution until ajax request finishes

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there a way to suspend jquery execution while waiting for requests to finish, so that you can track its progress? This is my code:

```
    $("span").click(function() {
        istrainning= true;
        for (var i=0;i<1000;i++)
            $.post("train.php",function(){
                $(".progressbar").width((i/10)+"%");
                $("label").html((i/10)+"%");
            });
    });
```

I want the statements

```
$(".progressbar").width((i/10)+"%");
$("label").html((i/10)+"%");
```

to execute only after finishing post request. please help.

--EDIT:

Sorry. It seems like my mistake is the 1000 requests being done all at the same time. is there a way to do it where all request will be done one at a time?

Comment: RTM http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ -> `success/done/fail`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: The terminology you use is a bit inaccurate but that's essentially exactly how the code you've posted will behave.

Comment: @MLeFevre The code is already inside the success callback (second parameter of `$.post()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are already inside the success callback so they *already will* execute after the POST is complete.

I believe your problem is that the loop is complete when the first ajax is done, and as such, `i` will always be `1000`

Have a look at http://fixingthesejquery.com/#slide55

I don't think posting a 1000 HTTP requests is a particularly good idea, but to avoid the `i` scoping issue, you can use a closure:

```
$("span").click(function() {
    istrainning= true;
    for (var i=0;i<1000;i++) {
        $.post("train.php",(function(i){
            return function() {
                $(".progressbar").width((i/10)+"%");
                $("label").html((i/10)+"%");
            }
        })(i)); // supply i as a parameter to the IIFE
    }
});
```

#### Further reading

- IIFE:
  http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/
- Closure:
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: this will not give a consistent result... assume what will happen if the 1st request finishes after the 500th request... the the value will change from `50%` to `.1%`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes, that's a good point. Since it's a progress bar the width should be increased instead of set to a calculation based on the iteration count.

Answer (score 0):

You could append .done(function() {....}) to your code to get something to run when successfully completed.  .always() will run if successful or not.

[jQuery.post( ) .done( ) and success:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213495/jquery-post-done-and-success)

Comment: The second parameter to `$.post()` is the success callback (the same as `.done()`)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the wrong use of closure variable in a loop.

```
$("span").click(function () {
    istrainning = true;
    var counter = 0,
        handler = function () {
            counter++;
            $(".progressbar").width((counter / 10) + "%");
            $("label").html((counter / 10) + "%");
        }
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        $.post("/echo/html/", {
            html: '<b>' + i + '</b>'
        }, handler);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/o6qag0ro/) - simulates with only 5 loops

- [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)
- [Creating closures in loops: A common mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake)

Note: Sending a 1000 ajax requests is never a good design, hopefully it is just done to test something