# Call a function after POST

Tags: jquery

How do I call a jQuery function after the data is successfully post and display. Example is as below,

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#pr_no").change(function(){
        var pr_no = $('#pr_no').val();  

        $.post('../view-detail-purchase-pdf.php',
        {
            pr_no : pr_no
        }, function(data) {
            $('#result').html('<a href="../view-detail-purchase-pdf.php?pr_no=' + pr_no + '" class="popupwindow">' + pr_no + '</a>');
        })

    }); 

});
</script>
```

On the `$('#result')` `div` is a link that enable a pop up window if click using a jQuery plugin that have the `class="popupwindow"`. How do I make it work.

Comment: there something called success, looks like a repeated question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery.post( ) .done( ) and success:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213495/jquery-post-done-and-success)

Comment: provide the code for your popup click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the link is dynamically added you will need to delegate the click event for you popup

```
$('body').on('click','.popupwindow',function(){
// code for showing the popup window
});
```

or if you have a plugin you define it in the success function

```
$.post('../view-detail-purchase-pdf.php',
        {
            pr_no : pr_no
        }, function(data) {
            $('#result').html('<a href="../view-detail-purchase-pdf.php?pr_no=' + pr_no + '" class="popupwindow">' + pr_no + '</a>');
           $('.popupwindow').initPopup();//initiate your popup after appending the element on the page;
        })
```

Comment: **Thanks for the help**. Now I understand, we have to put the code after the success function is call.

Answer (score 3):

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" ); // this is what you may be looking for
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```