# jQuery - Execute 2 functions synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have created a submit function for each form created on my application. It's similar to the one written below.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
  //Some variable declaration
  $.ajax({
   type:'post',
   url:'someurl',
   data:formdata
   success:function(){
     console.log('form submitted');
   }
  });
});
```

No doubt this works fine. Now for one of the forms I want to update a certain element after the response is received, similar to this.

```
$('#customform').submit();
console.log('custom form submitted');
```

So in this case I want the message "custom form submitted" to be printed only after 'form submitted' message is printed to the console (Synchronous loading).
Anyone to help?

Comment: Your title is misleading. Nothing _synchronous_ with your code

Comment: There is option of `$.ajax({async: false})` but this will freeze your browser, I suggest you not to do it, better approach will be if you make the second ajax call in the first's success callback

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809056/how-to-add-additional-fields-to-form-before-submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include the code into the success function:

```
success:function(){
  console.log('form submitted');
  console.log('custom form submitted');
}
```

You can also add complete function, so the code will run no matter if error or success:

```
success:function(){
  console.log('form submitted');
},
complete: function() {
  console.log('custom form submitted');
}
```

as @Tomalak mentioned in the comment, the modern way to do it:

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
.done(function() {
  alert( "second success" );
})
.fail(function() {
  alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
  alert( "finished" );
});
```

can read more here: [jQuery.post( ) .done( ) and success:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213495/jquery-post-done-and-success)

Comment: The modern way to do this is to use the `.done()` and `.always()` promise callbacks. Compare: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213495/jquery-post-done-and-success

Comment: @Tomalak - Agree, but the OP added code with success function, other methods might confuse him if he follow guide or whatever reason.

Comment: @YanMayatskiy Thanks I wanted exactly what you said in "the modern way" to do it.

Comment: @SanketR- you should thank Tomalak, as he was the one who suggested to add it, but both of those ways are almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would take off `$("form").submit` eventlistener after forms finished submit, and add a custom one into it's success function

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"someurl",
        data:formdata,
        success:function(){
            console.log("form submitted");
            $("form").off("submit");

            $("#customform").submit(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"someurl",
                    data:modifiedFormdata,
                    success:function(){
                        console.log("custom form submitted");
                    }
                });
            }); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The OP does not want to send two Ajax requests.