# .then() doesn't wait till async function resolves promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await, promise

I have two functions. First contains jQuery.get().done() and it's return value is inside done() callback function, as showed below. (I have no idea if using jQuery matters here)

I may not be understanding something, but my functions looks similar to those in first w3 example: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_async.asp

```
async function A(){     
  jQuery.get("example.com").done(function(result){
    if (result.indexOf("Example")){
      console.log("sucess");
      return 1;
    } else {
      console.log("Fail");
      return -1;
    }
  })
}

function B(){
  A().then(function(result){
    console.log("Res:" + result);
  })
}

B();
```

But the output is:

> ```
> Res:undefined
>    // here some time passes for A() to complete.
> succes
> ```

So I can't understand why .then() doesn't wait for function A() to complete and resolve promise, but instead it acts immediately while result is not defined yet ?

Comment: That's because your function `A()` has no rreturn value.  Really, you ought to just use the promises built into jQuery and get rid of that use of `.done()`.  Use `.then()` instead.  Plus, there's no reason to tag a function `async` if you're not using `await` in it.  Your function needs to return a promise or it needs to await a promise and then return a value.

Answer (score 3):

This is much better written using actual promises (which jQuery supports) and `await` as follows:

```
async function A() {
    const result = await jQuery.get("example.com");
    if (result.indexOf("Example") !== -1) {
        console.log("sucess");
        return 1;
    } else {
        console.log("Fail");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. Stop using jQuery's `.done()`.  It's non-standard.  Use `.then()` or `await`.
2. Don't mix `await` with `.done()` or with `.then()`.  Use one model or the other.
3. There's no need for the `res` intermediate variable.  When you get rid of the `.done()`, you can just return the value directly.
4. Note, `.indexOf()` does not return a boolean.  It returns -1 if not found and an index of the position if found.  Best not to treat its return value as a boolean.

Comment: 1. I've just read about `.done()` vs `.then()` and you are right that using .then() is better. 2. I've added to my answer purely jQuery solution. 4. Thank you, it's a a bad mistake, it would falsely return true. I've fixed it in my program already, but I forgot about it in testing code.

Comment: But if you need  HTTP GET status code you still need to retrieve it from the inside of success callback function ?

Comment: @Gbr - You showed a coding example with a certain set of requirements.  I offered an example to those requirements.  Different requirements would naturally result in different code.  Personally, I would never use jQuery for http requests as the API is so convoluted, confusing and polluted and full of lots of legacy, not-promise-related stuff.  In a browser, I'd just use the `fetch()` interface which is built into every browser and is fully promise-compatible in every way.  For an interface with a few more features, I'd probably use `axios()`.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a jQuery thing in particular. It's just async JS in general. I'm [not sure you really need the .done() part at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213495/jquery-post-done-and-success) since you're using promises.

But anyway, you have two basic problems.

1. You need to return something inside of function A, not inside `.done()`. So you can return `jQuery.get()`.
2. In function B, you want to wait for function A to complete before hitting the `.then()` block. That means function B is also async. (In the simple example below you can omit the `async` keyword on function A.) You need to declare function B as `async` and then `await` the completion of function A.

```
function A() {
  return jQuery.get("example.com").done(function(result) {
    if (result.indexOf("Example")) {
      console.log("sucess", result);
    } else {
      console.log("Fail", result);
    }
  });
}

async function B() {
  await A().then(function(result) {
    console.log("Res:");
    // moved to a separate console log, otherwise dev tools might print
    // a lot of [objectObject] instead of the actual result
    console.log(result);
  })
}

B();
```

If you want to do other stuff inside of function A and then eventually return the result, you can play around with something more like

```
async function A() {
  const response = await jQuery.get('example.com');
  // more stuff…
  return response;
}
```

Comment: If you return whole jQuery chain, doesn't you return the whole jQuery object as a function result ? But how could I return just a value (1 or -1 as in my code) based on the result of get() request ?

Comment: "You need to return something inside of function A, not inside .done(). So you can return jQuery.get()." Why? Is it because if I put a `return` statement in the callback function ,then it's "not seen" from the outside of function A() as a return value of that function?

Comment: It returns the response of the GET request. That's how jQuery.get works. Inside function B, in the `then`, you can look through the response and do different stuff at that point. Or you can potentially try a `.then` instead of `.done` inside function A if you want to do that inside function A. Tbh I haven't used jQuery for AJAX before, but the post I linked seemed to suggest you probably want to use jQuery's `.then` function instead. To your second question: yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by moving return statement outside from the .done(function(){}) and by adding await before jQuery chain. And instead of returning value inside that callback function, now I only pass there value to variable, which is later returned outside of that callback function.

```
async function A(){     
 let res = 0; 
  await jQuery.get("example.com").done(function(result){ //await was added
    if (result.indexOf("Example")){
      console.log("sucess");
      res = 1; // value is passed to variable, which is returned as result outside this callback function
    } else {
      console.log("Fail");
      res = -1;
    }
  })
  return res; // return statement is outside the callback function
}

function B(){
  A().then(function(result){
    console.log("Res:" + result);
  })
}

B();
```

I guess the problem was, as @cjl750's answer says, that return statement inside the callback function isn't "seen" as a "true return statement" of that function. So function B() probably saw function A() as a function, which doesn't return anything.

---

### EDIT

I've rewritten the code using $.Deferred() object. It's probably better now. Await is now moved to function B(), it doesn't wait for jQuery chain anymore.

```
function A(){     
 var dfd = $.Deferred();
 jQuery.get("google.com").then(function(result){ 
    if (result.indexOf("Example")){
      console.log("sucess");
      dfd.resolve(1); 
    } else {
      console.log("Fail");
      dfd.resolve(-1); 
    }
  })
  return dfd.promise();
}

async function B(){
  await A().then(function(result){
    console.log("Res:" + result);
  })
}

B();
```

Comment: I was going to come back and update my answer with an example just like this, but you've figured it out already! Nice!

Comment: Please stop using `.done()`.  First off, you should do `let result = await jQuery.get(...);` and not mix `.done()` with `await`.  Then, if you must use something like `.done()`, use `.then()` instead.  Use the standard promise model that jQuery supports, not jQuery's funky one.  See my answer for a simplified approach.

Comment: There is NO reason to use a Deferred here - that's an anti-pattern because `jquery.get()` already returns a promise which you can just use.  You don't need to create your own Deferred.  And, one of the main reasons for making it an anti-pattern is that people usually screw up the error handling which you have messed up here.  If `jquery.get()` rejects, you don't handle that at all.